# Optical drive suffering from chronic premature ejection

Tags: disk, hardware, scsi, optical-media

My slot-loading optical drive (HP BDDVDRW CA21N) spins and up and then ejects every disc, a process that takes about 15 seconds. I've found lots of posts on enabling wanted ejects, but close to nothing on avoiding unwanted ones.

I have tried commenting out the relevant line in `/etc/fstab`, and using `sudo sysctl dev.cdrom.lock=1`, both making no change. `/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:0\:0\:0/device_b*` seems to always contain zeroes. Further system information follows:

```
brick@dowland:~$ uname -a
Linux dowland 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

brick@dowland:~$ sudo modprobe sr_mod

brick@dowland:~$ sudo dmesg
...
[4251487.063009] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[4251487.093385] debugfs: Directory 'sr0' with parent 'block' already present!
[4251487.093465] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0

brick@dowland:~$ lsscsi --long
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  hp       BDDVDRW CA21N    C2S2  /dev/sr0 
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=5 device_blocked=0 timeout=30

brick@dowland:~$ cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:0\:0\:0/state
running

brick@dowland:~$ cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0\:0\:0\:0/uevent 
DEVTYPE=scsi_device
DRIVER=sr
MODALIAS=scsi:t-0x05

brick@dowland:~$ cat  /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info 
CD-ROM information, Id: cdrom.c 3.20 2003/12/17

drive name:     sr0
drive speed:        24
drive # of slots:   1
Can close tray:     1
Can open tray:      1
Can lock tray:      1
Can change speed:   1
Can select disk:    0
Can read multisession:  1
Can read MCN:       1
Reports media changed:  1
Can play audio:     1
Can write CD-R:     1
Can write CD-RW:    1
Can read DVD:       1
Can write DVD-R:    1
Can write DVD-RAM:  1
Can read MRW:       1
Can write MRW:      1
Can write RAM:      1
```

Thank you for reading this far! What else should I look at?

Comment: Boot with a live cd, then see if it can be mounted there. If not, then the drive is likely broken. Or the cable is bad. Or the port is bad.

Comment: @Bib replacing the drive did the trick. Thanks for the tip.